# $\int_X g(x) d G(E) = \int_X g(x)f(x) d\mu (x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X, B, \mu)$ be a measure space. $f$ be an integrable function on $X$ and let
$$
G(E) := \int_E f(x) d \mu(x)
$$
for $E \in B.$
I want to show that for measurable function $g$,
$$
\int_X g(x) d G(x) = \int_X g(x)f(x) d\mu (x)
$$
holds. Actually I cannot understand what does the notation $\int.. dG(x)$ means. Please give me some help.

Comment: $G$ is a measure. That's $\int\cdots dG(x)$. It means integration with respect to the measure $G$.

Comment: @OpenBall oh thanks, but how can I show that the equality holds?

Comment: @M.Doe From openballs comment, can you see that G \|| \mu?